# distinguishable objects in distinguishable boxes except one box remains empty

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My professor told our class the answer to the question but I am looking for an explanation to help further understand this concept. The question is:

Suppose that *n* balls are placed into *n* boxes. Calculate the number fo different possible results if both balls and boes are distinguishable, and exactly one box remains empty.

He gave us that the answer is:

C(n,1) * C(n-1,1) * C(n,2) * [(n-2)]!

Comment: General math questions should be in the math forum

Answer (score 0):

C(n, k) - is, in general, how many possibles variants to choose k elements from n, and the order doesn't matter. 
C(n, 1) - is how many variants of choosing one empty box.
C(n-1, 1) - how many variants then to choose box with 2 elements.
C(n, 2) - how many variants is to choose 2 balls from n balls.
(n-2)! - how many variants to destribute other balls to other boxes;